# How to start week in Power BI from Friday

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to create a biweekly interval where Friday is first day of the week. I am stuck at trying to figure out if there's a function that will allow moving first day of the week to Friday.

I have tried the WEEKDAY() function, but it only allows start dates between Saturday, Sunday, Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a DAX Calculated Column with this:

```
Week Starting (fri) = 
  var wkd = WEEKDAY([Date], 2)
  return [Date] + IF(wkd > 4, 5, -2) - wkd
```

This will return the previous Friday date.

Comment: Thanks! I was working with a similar broken down formula with the default WEEKDAY start. 
Adjusted Day of Week = IF(WEEKDAY([Date]) >=6, WEEKDAY([Date]) - 5, WEEKDAY([Date]) + 2)

And then adjusting to start on Friday.

But your solution is more concise.